# UHD produces linker error in FreeBSD

Tags: gcc, freebsd, uhd

I'm on freebsd and trying to run uhd from: http://www.ettus.com/download This should normally run under freebsd, but I encounter problems when I try to build it like specified here:
http://www.ettus.com/uhd_docs/manual/html/build.html#build-instructions-unix

I get:

```
[ 73%] Building CXX object examples/CMakeFiles/benchmark_rx_rate.dir/benchmark_rx_rate.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable benchmark_rx_rate
../lib/libuhd.so.003.000: undefined reference to `uhd::set_thread_priority(float, bool)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 *** Error code 1
```

Now this seems to be a linker error, but how to get rid of it? I tried setting the path using ldconfig but this hasn't changed a thing. Maybe some of you have an idea where I could continue searching.

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right, libuhd get's built earlier by this CMake script. If it's true, this error indicates bug in their CMakeLists.txt files.
It looks like you are building examples of using libuhd. I doubt you are need them. So, either look for switches in your CMakeCache.txt and regenerate Makefiles or hack CMakeLists.txt to not include examples dir.

Another thing you may try - set CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS to -L/usr/local/include.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect situation for creating a FreeBSD port.  Since FreeBSD has its own consistent filesystem layout, compiler and linker flags often need to be modified (as noted by arrowdodger) slightly.

The ports system is a framework for persistently capturing those configuration changes and making any software package as easy to install as typing the commands:

cd /usr/ports/*category/application-name* && make install clean

In a perfect world, you would create the UHD port, submit it for review and addition to the tree.  If you need help learning how to do that, the [FreeBSD Porter's Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/) and the [freebsd-ports mailing list](http://lists.freebsd.org/mailman/listinfo/freebsd-ports) are excellent resources.